# MARIADB default users

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just installed mariadb 10.6 and can't understand...

```
SELECT Host,User,Password FROM mysql.user;
```

1. `mariadb.sys@localhost` password is empty.
2. `root@localhost` password hashed.
3. `mysql@localhost` password has "invalid" value in cell.

**SHOW CREATE USER 'mariadb.sys'@localhost\G;**

```
CREATE USER `mariadb.sys`@`localhost` ACCOUNT LOCK PASSWORD EXPIRE
```

**SHOW CREATE USER 'root'@localhost\G;**

```
CREATE USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED
VIA mysql_native_password USING '***' OR unix_socket
```

**SHOW CREATE USER 'mysql'@localhost\G;**

```
CREATE USER `mysql`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED
VIA mysql_native_password USING 'invalid' OR unix_socket
```

1. What for default users are?
   `root@localhost` = for me, `mariadb.sys@localhost` = for mariadb.sys system, `mysql@localhost` = for mysql user and for linux system.
2. I used `mysql_secure_installation` command. Do i really need do anything else? Is everything OK with secure?
3. Can I delete `mariadb.sys@localhost` or `mysql@localhost` users?
4. Why do I need to setup password for `mysql@localhost` user?
5. "invalid" in password cell means not password, but mariadb "secure feature"?
6. `ACCOUNT LOCK PASSWORD EXPIRE` what is this?
7. As far as I understand I can't and I don't need to setup password for `mariadb.sys@localhost`?

Thank you!

Versions:

- Kernel: linux510 (Linux 5.10.56-1)
- Distro: Manjaro 21.1.0 (Arch Linux)
- MariaDB Version: MariaDB 10.6.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. 

- `root@localhost` - you, but its also helpful if this is there, unmodified (setting a password is ok - as you have done, but keep the `OR unix_socket` part  for package updates
- `mariadb.sys@localhost` this is the owner of the `mysql.users` compatibility view, which is why its account is locked/password expired.
- `mysql@localhost` - I suspect this is some packaging decision to create this. It might be tied to logrotate or some monitoring system.

2. `mysql_secure_installation` - I can't tell if this changed anything from the default installation. Nothing else is needed.
3. No, don't delete these users. Understand why `mysql@localhost` exists, however its not usable by anything else, something needs to switch to the `mysql` unix user to be used.
4. you don't need to set a password for `mysql@localhost`.
5. `invalid` is a place holder of a hash that doesn't have a real password that maps to it. Its there so if a user desires, they can set a password on the account.
6. [ACCOUNT LOCK](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/account-locking/) is a locked account. [PASSWORD EXPIRE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-password-expiry/) is an expired password.
7. Changing `mariadb.sys@localhost` isn't needed. It is recommended you don't change this.